# Where to learn financial modelling concepts and skills?

Tags: finance, corporate-finance

I'm looking to learn more about the financial analysis of a business. Things like unit economics calculation, income statement, free cash flow analysis, a valuation calculation, etc.

Can you recommend a website or book that has simple explanations, formulas for these concepts without lengthy useless explanations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When I was studying for my bachelors we learned finance from textbook Corporate Finance by
Jonathan Berk. I think thats good entry into learning some basic financial analysis.